# How to call a function from outside the main function?

Tags: javascript, function

I am currently trying to learn javascript and what I want to achieve is to call a function, from outside the main function. For a better idea, I left the code which I am currently exercising on. I will be extremely grateful If someone can explain to me why exactly this function is not working. Thank you in advance.

```js
function One_Main(){
    function Alpha(){
        console.log("Alpha");
    }
}
One_Main(); 



function Two_Main(){
    Alpha();
}
Two_Main();
```

Comment: Another thing you should learn is that there are no *main functions* in JS :-)

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for pointing that out. From now on I will not do the same mistake twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because `Alpha` is not visible outside of `One_Main`.

To make it visible, you can define `One_Main` as an object, then make `Alpha` a property of `One_Main`.

To fix your code, do this:

```js
function One_Main() {
  this.Alpha = function() {
    console.log("Alpha");
  }
}

// Make it visible
Alpha = new One_Main().Alpha;

function Two_Main() {
  Alpha();
}
Two_Main();
```

### ES2015 Style

```js
class One_Main {
    constructor() {}
    static Alpha() {
        console.log("Alpha");
    }
}

// Make it visible
Alpha = One_Main.Alpha;

function Two_Main() {
    Alpha();
}

Two_Main();
```

### As a simple property in pure JS

```js
function One_Main() {}

One_Main.Alpha = function() {
  console.log("Alpha");
}

// Make it visible
Alpha = One_Main.Alpha;

function Two_Main() {
  Alpha();
}

Two_Main();
```

Comment: Don't ever write ES6 `class`es with only static members, with totally useless constructors. Just put an object literal instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer with all the examples which you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Alpha() is in the scope of One_Main, you can't see it from the global scope. To call Alpha() from outside of One_Main you need to declare it outside of that function.

```
function Alpha(){
    console.log("Alpha");
}

function One_Main(){
    Alpha();
}
One_Main(); 



function Two_Main(){
    Alpha();
}
Two_Main();
```

Comment: Thank you for the example you provided. I am very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read about scoping in javascript to understand the problem.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript

The function `Alpha` is not visible inside the `Two_Main` function

PS: Debugging is useful to learn more about the error. In Chrome you can right click and select Inspect element and look at the console to debug javascript.

[image]

Checkout https://raygun.com/blog/debug-javascript/ for more information

Comment: I would definitely check that. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what tutorial are you studying, maybe you are reading about `currying` method, if that is the case, you can make:

```js
function One_Main(){
    function Alpha(){
        console.log("Alpha");
    }
    return Alpha;
}
One_Main(); 

function Two_Main(){
    One_Main()();
}
Two_Main();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing a working example. I am very grateful.